# Ember JS,Pass input tag value as parameter in action handlbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to get value from `<input>` tag and pass it as parameter to action in EmberJS

When I used JQuery `{{action 'add' this.$('#x').val()}}` Ember failed to build giving `parse error on line ...`

Here I want to pass x and y as parameter to the `{{action}}`, I know the syntax for sending parameters is `{{action parameter1 parameter2 ..etc}}`

templates\alpha.hbs

```
<h1>alpha template</h1>
<div>
 <label>X value</label>
 <input type="text" id="x">
 <label>Y</label>
 <input type="text" id="y">
 <input type="button" id ="add-button" value="Add" {{action 'add' }}>
</div>
```

controllers\alpha.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    add: function(x, y){
      alert('this is done right '+x+ ' ' + y);
    }
  }
});
```

I tested the code without passing parameters and the code worked as expected giving the alert required

Comment: Why not have your inputs in a form and have the form fire an action on submit?

Comment: well, having multiple buttons with different number of parameters in the same form won't help with submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take advantage of `input` helpers and value binding in Ember:

```
<br><h1>alpha template</h1>
<div>
 <label>X value</label>
 {{input value=xValue}}
 <label>Y</label>
 {{input value=yValue}}
 <input type="button" id ="add-button" value="Add" {{action 'add' xValue yValue}}/>
</div>
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/97bdd14f8ccef48bb0c5)
- [Full code behind demo.](http://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/97bdd14f8ccef48bb0c5)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for the links